# Inferring composition of a subset of classes of multiclass dataset

Tags: classification, dataset, classifier

I've come across a problem in assessing the design of a Machine Learning solution I am involved in, which I will describe using a commonly known dataset, the [Iris Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris), and some drawings.

Suppose you have training information about the 3 flower classes contained in the Iris Dataset, which means you can train a multivariate classifier that can distinguish between these 3 flower classes.

However, my dataset 4 classes of flowers, i.e. one extra class that the classifier hasn't been trained on. This dataset I call the "Main" dataset.  The classification is guaranteed to pick one of the 3 Iris Dataset classes, meaning you 100% misclassify any instance's of the 4th class not included in training.
[image]

The objective I have is to figure out the Main dataset's composition in the 3 Iris flower classes. I am trying to do this with a second dataset, which I call the "Auxiliary" dataset, containing ONLY the 4th extra class, with a size equal to the expected number of the 4th class's instances in the 4-class dataset. Thus, I get a picture of the possible outcome of using the Iris Classifier on the 4th flower class.
[image]
Using the above, is it safe to infer the composition of the Main dataset in the 3 Iris classifier classes, by subtracting the composition of the instances based on the 4th class auxiliary dataset?

> "Main" composition in Iris classes = "Main" output composition -
> "Auxiliary" output composition

Is there perhaps any literature relative to this?